# "In a broad range of positions" or "on a broad range of positions"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

I'm writing a cover letter and need to know the proper way of saying this:

> Over the last ten years I had the opportunity to work for multinational companies **in/on** a broad range of management positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work in a position. You do not work on a position, unless you are practicing a new sex technique, which is probably not what you want. Not in this context, anyway.